# Changed Python version, "apt-add-repository" not working ERROR

Tags: apt, updates, python, repository

hi after installed python 3.5 in ubuntu, i had 2.7.6 and i wanted to be updated cause i will be working and learning python, so i installed the latest python version 3.5 and switched version to it, i have python 2.7 & 3.5 installed but set it to 3.5 as default, after making that change and update i got this error:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:example/example -y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

at the moment is the only one i encounter besides cant remove any python version it would break the system ,any help about how to fix it? :(

```
$ update-alternatives --query python
Name: python
Link: /usr/bin/python
Status: manual
Best: /usr/bin/python3.5
Value: /usr/bin/python2.7
Alternative: /usr/bin/python2.7
Priority: 1
Alternative: /usr/bin/python3.5
Priority: 2

$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3754856 dic 18 09:58 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3345416 jun 22  2015 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? How exactly did you install python 3.5, and how did you make it the default?

Comment: 14.04 , i installed from a official ppa and then, i make it default using this instructions... http://bit.ly/1n55JEC (system wide)

Comment: If you used the `update-alternatives` method described in your link, then you should be able to set it back by running `update-alternatives --config python` and following the on-screen instructions to select `python2.7`

Comment: i did that, but the problem still, even if i reboot the pc

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of the following commands: `update-alternatives --query python`, `readlink -f $(which python)`, `ls -l /usr/bin/python?.?`

Comment: there you go, the "readlink -f $(which python)" doesnt get me much just this

 "readlink -f $python2.7
/home/alejandro/.7"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33941/discussion-between-alexdmz-and-steeldriver).

Comment: You shouldn't delete or modify the default Python. Set the default back to the old Python and everything should work again.

Answer (score 0):

For Python3.5 use the command

```
alias python=python3.5
```

and for Python2.7 use

```
alias python=python2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56234758/52817:

If you look at `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` it says

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
```

at the top. If you updated with a newer python (e.g. dist had 3.5 but you installed 3.7) your `/usr/bin/python3` points to a python that does not have `apt_pkg`.

You can temporarily edit `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` to point to

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.5
```

(insert your distro python version)